# Why are webp files not displayed in aab?

Tags: java, android, webp

When I upload my app to Google Console and download it from the Play Store the images in webp format are not shown, but in my virtual device they can be seen. Here is in my virtual phone:

[image]

In Google Play I got this:

[image]

The code of my adapter to load the images is the following:

```
public void bind(final FruitList fruitList, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        Glide.with(context).load(loadImage(fruitList.getFruitPicture())).into(fruitImage);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onItemClick(fruitList, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

private int loadImage(String mImageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(mImageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

In my database I only have the name of the image and with the loadImage method of my Adapter class I get the integer. The funny thing is that when I use a webp image directly in an ImageView, if I load them.

Comment: It is possible that the webp image from fruitList.getFruitPicture() is not https?

Comment: @Mike no, all the webp are in my drawable folder, are local. In my virtual phone works, but when I upload my aab in Play Store, the images are gone

Comment: What is the OS version of virtual device? lossy webp can be supported up until API Level 14 and lossless API Level 18, also have you tried setting it to ImageView directly through class instead of having Glide do it.

Comment: @Mike it's Android 10, I was looking into the aab file with winrar and I'm noticing that all the weps are zero size.

Comment: @Mike my min SDK is 19 and the target SDK is 29

Comment: @Mike I have another project with jpg and png images, and I saw that aab is making this images with zero size.

Comment: have you tried to put your  webp images in Asset folder ?

Comment: @Mike and Nagvadiya Vishal I solved the problem, check my answer. Thanks for being interested in helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching in developer android and I found something about the Shrink. The part that I read is in the next link - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#strict-reference-checks

But in general says that Shrink will ignore every resource or code that you don´t use, so I made a method that dynamically-generated strings, in my case I generated the name of my picture, so Shrink ignored all my pictures because I never used it or call it in my code or my layouts.

So, the recommendation of Android says that I need to use String.format to generated my dynamically strings.

The method in Java is the next:

```
String name = String.format("img_%1d", angle + 1);
res = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

In my case I used that in the following way:

```
private int loadImage(String mImageName) {
    String newName = String.format("if_%1$s", mImageName.substring(3, mImageName.length()));
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(newName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

And that´s it, works perfectly. Thanks Mike and Nagvadiya Vishal for being interested in helping me.

Comment: Ah this make sense, since you are shrinking the app it ignores the dynamically introduced webp resources thinking that you aren't using it. Yup using the .format actually solves your problem.